# Can websites use ad blocker detection to take you away from the page wanted?

Tags: adblock

[In the comments](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/28722/is-natural-labor-beneficial-to-a-vaginal-delivery#comment54011_28722) of a question in MedicalSciences.SE, it was stated that the second link in the OPs question was broken, but then later in the next comment you can see that it was found that

> my ad blocker was somehow causing the article to be immediately replaced with a general landing page. I have no idea how an ad blocker could do that, but once I turned it off for that site, the article appeared.

Is there a known way I could use ad blocker detection techniques to divert the visitor to a different page?

Comment: I'm not sure that theory is correct.  I use Adblock Plus in Firefox and the link works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The link in question worked fine for me (and I use an ad blocker) but this behavior is certainly possible.

It is possible to detect ad blockers - indeed there are multiple ways to do so.  Once an ad blocker has been detected  it is possible to change the content shown or redirect the user behind it.

Comment: I personally detest adblock detection and I don't use it on any of my sites.   If you do want to use it, it would make sense to do so in a manner that is as user-friendly as possible.   Tell the user that ad block was detected.  Give users clear paths to see the content and make it as easy as possible for them to do so. That could means allowing user to see the content with an acknowledgement click, showing subscription options, or providing instructions for disabling ad block. Redirecting to some other page that doesn't explain what went wrong is poor user experience and could hurt your site.